# Where to ask questions that fall into "Information security SE" and "Unix & Linux SE"?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions about security of my computer, digital or informational security, for which there is an [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) site.

The questions are also about security in a Linux Operating System, for which there is a [Stack Exchange community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and for Ubuntu which also has a [Stack Exchange site](https://askubuntu.com/).

Where to ask them?

Answer (score 2):

[Nathan's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275807/155160) and [Robert's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/275800/155160) answers are on point, but also... Who do you want to hear from? Security experts or Linux experts? Tailoring your question to the right audience may get you better responses.

Posting to both sites is also fine, provided you rephrase appropriately to stress the points relevant to each community. It's a "help them help you" kind of deal - the more you tailor to the site audience, the better the answer you're gonna get.

Answer (score 1):

You could ask in the [DMZ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz) (which is the security chat room) whether your question would be on topic for [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).

Alternatively you could ask a question on the [Information Security Meta](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/). If so try to provide as much information as possible e.g. an example question.

You may also find checking out the site's [help centre](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) useful.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good chance your question will fit well on any of the sites listed. Ask Ubuntu, if I'm not mistaken, caters a little more toward the GUI-friendly, end-user crowd than Unix & Linux, which is more goatees and CLI hacks that work across multiple distros. InfoSec handles things from a perhaps more generalized security standpoint, but it's still practical (as opposed to Crypto's theoretical approach), so the real question is which experts you expect to get the best answers from, keeping in mind that many users are active on two or three of those sites.

If you like, you can ask the same basic question on multiple sites at once; however, there are two strong caveats to this. First is that you have to customize the question to focus on the particular site's strengths; cross-posting identical questions will likely get you downvotes or closevotes on some or all of the sites once someone finds out what you're doing. (If you don't know what the sites' strengths are well enough, this is probably impractical, and you shouldn't even try.) Second, be clear that this is what you're doing; seeming to hide a cross-post just makes people less friendly toward your posts, and you.

Comment: Goatees? Am I that old?  [RFC 2323](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2323) clearly states "Long-term versus short-term facial hair is a very important distinction as short-term facial hair, also known as the temporary illness "goatee universitis" (which symptoms range from full goatees to the less popular chin-goatee) is a common affliction for university-based males."